# php+socket.io+mysql - Messenger like chat

Tags: php, mysql, socket.io, chat

I'm trying to build up a chat server, and I'm on the right track:

I've got a PHP file that generates a vertification-token,
I've got the server set up that handles the messages if the token is valid.

---

But I am a bit confused.
I would like to verify if USER 1 and USER 2 are frieds / are in the same group chat. If not, then I'd like to deny the message: just like in facebook, you can't message a person if they are not added as friends.

**The server file:**

```
var app = require('express')(); // app
var server = require('http').Server(app); // on http create server
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socketioJwt   = require("socketio-jwt"); // JWT for authentication

var chatRooms = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', socketioJwt.authorize({
    secret: 'xxx',
    timeout: 2000
})).on('authenticated', function(socket) {

    //this socket is authenticated, we are good to handle more events from it.
    console.log('User connected and authenticated (' + socket.decoded_token.nickName + ' (' + socket.decoded_token.userId + '))');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('User disconnected (' + socket.decoded_token.nickName + ' (' + socket.decoded_token.userId + '))');
    });


    socket.on('subscribe', function() { 
        socket.join(socket.decoded_token.userId); 
        console.log('subscribed ');
    });

    socket.on('unsubscribe', function() {  
        socket.leave(userId); 
    });

    socket.on('send', function(data) {
        var messageData = {
            "userId": socket.decoded_token.userId,
            "toUserId": data.toUserId,
            "chatId": data.chatId,
            "users": [socket.decoded_token.userId, data.toUserId],
            "message": data.message
        };
        io.sockets.in(data.toUserId).emit('message', messageData);
        io.sockets.in(socket.decoded_token.userId).emit('message', messageData);
        console.log('msg sent');


    });
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

---

Should I do that with an implemented Mysql database check in the server file,
 or should I use I don't know, more tokens? Or what do you think? Is there a common way to verify?

I'd like to save the messages to my database, so whenever the user sends a message it does 2 things:

- It calls a PHP file that verifies if user1 and user2 are friends, and if so, then saves the message in the database
- It sends the message to my server and passes on real time to user 2. (I need to check friendship here too)

---

Actually I don't have a clue how could I synchronize

1. verifying
2. saving to the database
3. sending real time

I have read articles and blogs about this, but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you have issues with sending the messages to the receiver in real-time. If so, you will need to ask a separate question dealing with that. In my answer I will be focusing on the friendship relation you need to define.

In general friendship is symmetric, so if A is friends with B, then B is friends with A.

So, if A wants to become friends with B, then A somehow sends a friend request, which should be an API call. B should receive such a request and if B accepts it, then A and B are friends.

For this purpose you will need to have a table for friend requests. You will insert a record whenever such a request is issued and remove such a record when a decision about the friend request is made. If the decision is acceptance, then you will need to somehow store that A and B are friends.

You can do that by using a table for friends, where you store the ids of users who happen to be friends. So, the model of the two tables we have spoken about could look like this:

> friendship_requests(id, sender_id, receiver_id)
>
> friends(id, user1_id, user2_id)

make sure that (sender_id, receiver_id) is unique and (user1_id, user2_id) is unique as well. You might want to index the tables to improve performance.

You could also create rooms where people might chat, who are not necessarily friends. For instance, if I enter the baseball room, then I can send and receive messages from people who are not my friends, but are inside the baseball room as well.

So, a message needs to have the following attributes:

- roomID
- senderID
- receiverID

If both the sender and the receiver are inside the same room or they are friends, then such a message needs to be stored in the database and sent to receiver.

Comment: I have problems with the one you explained in your reply: thank you very much, and I did already that: I have a PHP file that check wether the users are firends, and if so then it stores the message in the database. - But I don't know what would be a safe way to synchronize the PHP and the Socket.io server process. So my App sends the msg to the PHP file, it validates & saves in the db, then it returns back "success". Now, should my App send the msg to the server too, and without any more validation it should forward the msg?It seems hackable to me.Do I need validation on the server side too?

Comment: @AndrasKarpati messages should go through the server with validation. You will need to store the messages on the server, so that people logging in with a different device can load their messaging history, that is a very important reason, but not the only one. Another reason is that otherwise it is hackable and difficult to track indeed. And finally, András, not having the server as a middle-man would be too committal in my opinion. For instance, if a user decides to DDoS other users, then your app will lose popularity and you will not know why.